# Save Qlikview file to share point using load script

Tags: sharepoint, qlikview

Hi I have a qlikview file which i load everyday and save the QVD file to a Sharepoint. Can I load the file and save the QVD to the sharepoint using the load script?

Comment: (without knowing the answer) what about mapping the sharepoint location as network drive and read/write to the network drive?

Comment: That actually works! Thanks!